# Voltage requirement for integrated circuits

Tags: voltage, integrated-circuit, power-electronics

There are industry standard voltage levels for integrated circuits i.e. 12, 5, 3.3, 1.0, 1.05, 1.08, 0.6 V, etc.

Why make it so complex with this many voltage levels, why not just have one voltage level like 12 V to be universally used across all ICs?

Potential answers that I expect are about power drawn involving current holding capacity, copper losses, etc. but it would be nice to have a good explanation from industry technologist who have spent many years in electronics.

Comment: Why not have just one USB connector standard? Why not have just one wall outlet standard? Why not have just one spoken language?

Comment: is there room for simplification?

Comment: Is there room for simplification? Of course. But there seems to be economic reasons for diversification, or else all the chipmakers wouldn't be making different designs to fit different customer's needs.

Comment: rsg1710 nails it on the head. Historically, IC's needed higher voltages to even activate the transistors. Now the transistors are so small, if you applied that same voltage, you'd let the magic smoke out. Then there's low power and heat concerns to be worried about as well.

Comment: 0.6V IC... really.. ?

Comment: I have always wondered how they came up with the odd numbers though. You would think they would be multiples of a cell voltage, like, 1.5. 3.0, 4.5, 9 and 12V.

Comment: @Trevor Perhaps they want to encourage people to buy boost / buck converters.

Comment: @HarrySvensson lol maybe. Back when I, and TTL, started though such things did not exist, and SMPS were rare and expensive. Even LDO regulators were not available, you were basically stuck with a hot 7805 and CMOS was deemed too unreliable before they improved and we learned how to handle ESD. I have always wondered how many battery operated TTL gizmos just never got developed because the cost to power them made them a non-starter.

Comment: @Trevor_G: You're thinking only of Alkaline cells - what about lead-acid, lithium and perhaps other cell chemistries that produce different voltages.  Also, I suspect the majority of electronics work from AC power, not batteries, where cell voltage is irrelevant.

Answer (score 6):

The technology trend on ICs are to have them become smaller, faster, cost effective and low power consuming. Shrinking of transistor size is the major drive in this industry but shrinking the size leads to smaller voltage tolerance of breakdown that's is one of the reason why the supply voltage reduces the other being low power consumption of course.

Having said that certain application needs certain ICs with certain requirements for example power ICs are needed to handle high voltage, no escaping that. Or Analog circuits such as amplifier if one requires a high gain then one has to go for an amp with probably higher gain (with higher supply voltage) and so on...

Comment: Appreciate the response :)

Comment: Great answer. You've explained why voltages are dropping. Could be improved by explaining why we still have higher voltage applications such as analog, RS232, 4to20 mA and PLCs.

Comment: @lm317 thank you :) the second part of my answer does address to that as well :) thank you for bringing up specific examples :)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer for low core voltage in IC's: obtaining improved power, speed, density and cost made possible by ever-shrinking process nodes requires a co-dependent relationship with core voltage.

First, voltage vs. power.

There's two types of power dissipated in an IC:

- static (leakage) power: residual current due to incomplete FET turn-off
- dynamic (switching) power: current used to charge and discharge downstream loads

Static power is pretty easy to understand. It is modeled as a resistance as all the p- and n-FET pairs leaking in parallel, and so its power is simply \$P = E^2/R\$. The lower the voltage then, the lower the leakage power, squared.

Dynamic power takes into account switching frequency, capacitance and voltage, as \$P = 1/2CV^2\$. \$C\$ is calculated from the summed capacitance of all the driven signals as they charge and discharge their loads. Again, note the squared power-to-voltage relationship.

So even before you get into fiddling with process, reducing Vdd voltage is a win (squared) for power.

Now, process vs. voltage vs. speed.

Deep-submicron logic employs transistors that use thinner oxides and shorter channel lengths. Thinner oxide allows lower threshold voltage for faster switching, and shorter channel also reduces switching time. Yay, more speed!

But, thinner oxide means lower gate-source breakdown voltage. Shorter channel length meanwhile reduces source-drain breakdown voltage. Low threshold FETs also leak more.

Which brings us back to that co-dependency between deep-submicron logic and low Vdd. In fact, small-geometry FETs with thin oxide, low-threshold gates would be impossible to use without also reducing Vdd.

But we're not done yet. Deep-submicron technology is infamous for a major problem: leakage. This is mitigated by advances such as Silicon-on-Insulator and FinFET technology, which keep static power consumption in check, if not reduced outright.

The news gets better on the dynamic side: smaller geometry has less driven capacitance, which decreases \$1/2fVC\$ power at a given frequency.

The result? Smaller-process node ICs actually use less power overall than their equivalent in a bigger process node. A rule of thumb is that for every halving of channel length you net about 1/3 power reduction, before accounting for SoI or FinFET adoption.

So, another double-header win (power, and speed) for lower voltage.

That's great for the core, but what about the rest of the system?

Most bigger ICs split the difference by using multiple supplies: low-voltage cores, and higher voltage I/O. The I/O is handled by bigger, thick-oxide FETs in the near-pad circuits that can withstand the higher I/O voltages needed by the rest of the system. This allows the low-voltage optimized core to work at its best, while maintaining I/O compatibility with support chips.

There is a penalty for mixed voltages: extra fab steps to make the thick oxide FETs, more area set aside for both the higher-voltage transistors and the translation to/from core, and of course more power pins. All of which increase wafer cost (and the pins, package cost.)

Nevertheless, for a core-limited die, by using a smaller process you get all of that cost back - and more - by reducing your die size. You get more chips per wafer, even if the wafers themselves are more expensive than a larger process node.

The takeaway: reducing logic voltage helps power, while enabling smaller process geometry which in turn enables greater logic density, higher speed, and lower cost.

It's not an overstatement to say that today's paradigm-shifting electronic products we take for granted, like smartphones and broadband, would have been impossible without chip designers taking maximum advantage of process technology. The seeming 'annoyance' of multiple supplies is a small price to pay for this incredible progress.

Thus, as process has evolved, so we have witnessed core voltage migrate from 5, to 3.3, to 1.8, to 1.5, to 1.2, to 1.0, to 0.8, and lately (2023), to 0.6V for advanced 5nm processes.

By now I've hopefully convinced you of the value of using low voltage IC core supplies. Now, why the continued use of higher voltages in systems?

System power is a different problem set than an IC. In systems, we're dealing with multiple loads that are physically separated. Because of this, it's often better to increase the voltage and thus decrease the current being shipped around to the loads, allowing smaller wires and reducing \$P = I^2R\$ wire losses, then convert the voltage locally at the load as needed (this is called *Point of Load* regulation.)

For example, a GPU board will be supplied with 12V from its slot and cabled power connections, which gets converted locally to very high current (100's of A) 1.0-ish V core supply. Point-of-load regulation deals with this very effectively. Otherwise it would be impractical to power the GPU if it were obliged to run on 12V (see above), or if the motherboard had to supply 100A at 1.0V-ish over cabling with almost no IR drop.

Another example, LED strings with LED wired in series may use 24, 36, or 48V, current-regulated. Wiring and driving this way is not only more efficient than running them in parallel, but also ensures consistent brightness between LEDs as they're all seeing the same current.

Taken to an extreme, we see ever-higher voltages being used for electric vehicles (800V in the Porsche Taycan for example): it's easier to stuff more volts down the wire into the motor coils than it is to upsize the wires carrying the current. This practicality is also why the bigger (Level 3) EV chargers use 480V 3-phase power instead of 120 or 240V.

We're fortunate that we live in an age where power electronics have evolved to the point where we can efficiently optimize the voltage / current tradeoff to make the most of the system using it. New developments in power supply design, such as GaN and SiC devices are already making an impact in handling ever-higher voltages and currents, and advanced poly-phase switchers deal with power-hungry GPUs, CPUs and other big chips.

In other words, today we have a whole power ecosystem that allows us to tailor the voltage to the load, rather than the load to the voltage.

This wasn't the case in the mid-1970s when I started out in electronics. Then, 5V TTL was still regarded as state-of-the-art, while switching regulators were considered exotic and costly.

Still, 5V persists today as a kind of 'Goldilocks' voltage that is high enough to do useful hobby-tronics stuff like run motors, blink lights and power radios; yet low enough to not result in ridiculous power consumption for small systems.

Answer (score 2):

The elephant in the room is often getting the heat out as much as breakdown voltage at this point (Time was that was not so much the case).

For a CMOS device power is usually dominated by switching losses which go linearly in frequency and as the square of the voltage (1/2 CV^2 and all that), so going from 5V to 1V for core power is a huge (~25 times) saving in dynamic heat generation and that matters as clocks speed up.

At the same time, generating low voltages at large currents has become cheap and easy, tens of amps at 1V is trivial with a modern polyphase buck converter. While the 1V for the core, 1.2V for the DDR, 1.8V for the LVDI IO, 2.5V for the Aux IO thing is a little annoying, the inductors required to generate these do not integrate into a silicon process well (On chip magnetics tend to be poor for doing power things), so the supplies need to be separate (Besides the chip vendor cannot know what else I might be running off any given rail, so how do you size it?).

What we are seeing in modern designs is a rail of typically about 12V being regulated on card to whatever that particular circuit needs, (another symptom of cheap switchmode converters), you seldom see a supply having 12/5/3.3 outputs all taken to various circuit boards any more (at tens of amps), it is all either 12V or 48V (sometimes, -48V in the telecomms world for corrosion reasons) regulated down at point of load. This has many advantages starting with simplified wiring, and the fact that the higher bus voltage suffers less for voltage drops, and extending to the fact that an on card POL regulator can trivially easily sense the actual voltage at the load device.